# access violation reading location 0xfeef002A

Tags: c++, visual-studio, access-violation

How to see in visual studio whether the address is also accessed from somewhere else at the same time?

what can be the different reasons access violation is cause?

Comment: Have you tried looking in the call stack window?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking in the first part of your question.  Could you try rephrasing it?  Or posting the sample code causing this problem?

Comment: The error is because you are reading a virtual memory address which does not correspond to allocated memory. Without seeing code it's impossible to say much more. Most likely you are trying to read memory that has earlier been deallocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks very close to one of the [special values](http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html#table) used by the Visual Studio runtime debug heap.  There are a number of values that the C runtime uses after memory has been allocated and deallocated so that you can diagnose memory corruption errors more easily.  The value `0xFEEEFEEE` is used after memory has been freed.

I suspect what may be happening in your code is that an object has been deallocated but you still have a pointer to it (a *dangling pointer*) and you're trying to access a member variable of that object.  There are several things you could do to diagnose this problem, depending on the complexity of your code.  One is to enable [Page Heap Verification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543097%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and the other is to add some breakpoints in the destructor of the class that is being dereferenced so find out where the object is being destroyed so you can reset the other pointers that reference it.  Consider using smart pointers such as `shared_ptr<>` to reduce the likelihood of dangling pointers.

Comment: can access violating reading location happen possibly because two threads are writing to the same location at same time?

Comment: Possibly, though in most cases you would just get a race condition because the change made by one thread would be lost.  I think the key thing here is that the address 0xFEEExxxx is bogus, it's not a real memory location.  I think a destructor got called on your object, the memory released and the debug heap replaced the contents with 0xFEEEFEEE, then somehow you're getting an offset relative to that.